# Unable to transfer clicks/touches to windows below in android app

Tags: android, imageview, overlay, transparency

I want to make my app to be always over all other windows, and have the clicks pass through to the other windows below. The following code is being used as of now (taken from various places in stackoverflow :) :

Under onCreate, I call:

```
checkDrawOverlayPermission();
```

Below is the code for the checkDrawOverlayPermission(). An intent is started for getting user permission for starting the app as an overlay:

```
public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            /** if not construct intent to request permission */
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            /** request permission via start activity for result */
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult() section is as below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
            ...

        case REQUEST_CODE:
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    0 | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE;
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
            wm.addView(imagePane, params);

            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The manifest file has the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

The imagePane (ImageView) that is added as a view to the overlay, has the following properties set in activity_main.xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

With the above code, the app is appearing as a transparent window over the main screen of the phone. However, clicks or touches are not being received by the windows below this app. I tried running

> imagePane.setEnabled(false);

It does disable the clicks over the imagePane, but the clicks are still not received by the windows below this app. Any idea how to get the clicks to be received by windows below the app?

Comment: Any help would be great

Comment: Is there a solution for this. Request you to please help